# Utilizar função do mesmo pacote com Golang

Tags: golang

Dentro do meu projeto tenho 2 arquivos, `main.go` e `price.go`; em meu arquivo `main.go` dentro da função `main()` eu tentei chamar uma função do arquivo `price` que é exportável (começa com letra maiúscula), e ao tentar executar recebo o erro de que a função não foi definida;

> ./main.go:13:30: undefined: GetPrice

#### Código:

`main.go:`

```py
package main

import ( ... )

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    // Router registry for "/price" endpoint
    router.HandleFunc("/price", GetPrice).Methods("POST")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

`price.go:`

```py
package main

import (...)

// Price represent all fields in prices request
type Price struct {
    SKU       string  `json:"sku"`
    SellerID  string  `json:"seller_id"`
}

// GetPrice retrieve a json response to requested price
func GetPrice(writter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Hello! GET PRICE!")
}
```

Mesmo declarando uma função "exportável" porque continuo recebendo este erro?

Comment: Não vejo nenhum problema, você está usando o `go run`? Use o `go build` ou `go run *.go`.

Comment: @Inkeliz o problema era o `run` como você comentou, eu estava executando apenas `go run main.go`, quando executei `go run *.go` funcionou.
Por favor, coloque como resposta para que eu possa marcar como resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

O `go run` apenas executará o arquivo que mencionar, por exemplo `go run main.go`. Se o código estiver espalhado em vários arquivos ele não será lido, o que torna a função inexistente.

Existem algumas maneiras de corrigir:

- `go run main.go price.go`: Irá executar os dois arquivos.
- `go run *.go`: Irá executar todos os arquivos do mesmo diretório.
- `go build`: Irá compilar os arquivos do mesmo diretório, mas não executando ao terminar.

---

*Note que usar dependências/pacotes, mesmo que tenham mais de um arquivo, funcionarão normalmente quando se utiliza o `go run`. Então, o `import` não é problema, exceto se estiver configurado um GOPATH inválido.*